# Can we expect that $\mathcal{F}L^1(\mathbb R^d) \subset H^s(\mathbb R^d)$ for $s<0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\mathcal{F}L^1 (\mathbb R^d)= \{ f: \hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)\}$ and standard Soboleve space norm is $\|f\|_{H^s} = \| \langle \cdot \rangle^s \hat{f}\|_{L^2}$ where $\langle \cdot \rangle = (1+ |\cdot|^2)^{1/2}.$

> My Questions is: Can we expect that $\mathcal{F}L^1(\mathbb R^d) \subset H^s(\mathbb R^d)$ for $s<0$? If not, any counter example?

Comment: No. In fact if $\phi:\Bbb R^n\to[0,\infty)$ satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty}\phi(x)=0$ then there exists $f\in L^1$ with $|\hat f|\ge\phi$.

Comment: Yes, and actually, that is the same as asking if $L^1$ is embedded in some weighted $L^2$ space ... but it is easy to find a function in $L^1$ that is not locally in $L^2$. Then just take the Fourier transform of this function.

Comment: @LL3.14: Thanks.   Do you mean to say $\mathcal{F}L^1 \subset H^{s}$ for $s<0$?

Comment: No, I say I agree with David Ullrich, this is false. Rewrite $g=\hat{f}$. Then you are asking "if $g$ is in $L^1$, is $g$ in $L^2(\langle x\rangle^s)$?". But this is false since $g$ could not even be in $L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}$.